# Consistent popping sound while playing audio through a SourceDataLine

Tags: java, audio-player

I'm writing a basic synth at the moment and have run into a bit of a strange problem. I get a constant popping sound while playing an array of bytes, representing 16 bit mono audio, through a SourceDataLine.

The pops play at a constant rate, and from what I can hear, pitch. The pops do slightly differ in frequencies though (again, from what I can hear), some notes have low-passed sounding pops, and others sound high-passed. The pops are not overriding though, you can still hear the desired sound in the background.

Nothing changes the rate of the pops, not note pitch, not the SourceDataLine buffer size, not the number of bytes I write to it at a time, except sample rate.

Lowering the sample rate decreases the rate of the pops and vice-versa.

To test my side of the program, I printed out the data being written to the SourceDataLine for about half a second and looked through around 15 cycles of the played sine wave, and it was completely fine; no sudden jumps, clipping, or anything else.

The only two things I use the value of the sample rate for is some basic math to help my sampler sample at the correct frequency, which is only calculated once for each note, and is definitely working as pitch is perfect, and for creating the SourceDataLine.

Here's how I'm starting the SourceDataLine (Taken from multiple parts of the main method):

```
AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioEnvironment.SAMPLE_RATE, AudioEnvironment.BIT_DEPTH, 1, true, true);

SourceDataLine line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(format);
line.open(format, 8000);
line.start();
```

My data is correctly in big-endian, tested by me changing the endian flag in the constructor and getting my ears blasted with white noise.

After the program has set everything up, it constantly writes data to the SourceDataLine in this infinite loop:

```
while (true) {              
    for (Channel channel : channelSystem.getChannels()) {
        if (channel.pitch != 0) {
            wave.sample(channel, buffer);

            line.write(buffer, 0, AudioEnvironment.SUB_BUFFER_SIZE * 2);
        }
    }
}
```

(A `Channel` is a class I created that contains all the data for a single note (Though obviously the program is not set up correctly for polyphony at the moment), `buffer` is an array of bytes, `wave.sample()` is where I sample my data into `buffer`, and `AudioEnvironment.SUB_BUFFER_SIZE * 2` is the size of `buffer`)

I don't necessarily need an example of how to fix this in code, but an explanation of why this might be happening would be great.

EDIT: Something I should also probably add is that I've tried putting a print statement in the infinite write loop to print out the number of available bytes in the SourceDataLine, and it stays constantly around 500 - 2000, occasionally getting up to around 5000, but never near 8000, so the buffer is never running out of data.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a small standalone program (that doesn't depend on a separate `Channel` class)?

Comment: I'm confused by your statement that the pops play at a constant "pitch" but different "frequencies". Isn't the pitch determined by the frequencies?

Comment: @ruakh In this case, I don't think it should matter; like I said above, I've looked through the data generated by wave.sample() and it's fine. Channel at the moment only contains variables and constructors. The only parts of the code that could be going wrong is the first code snippet and line.write(). That, being said, I'll see if I can write a small, single class program to replicate my problem.

Comment: @ruakh I guess in general they would be a bit ambiguous, but for midi/synths, pitch would normally refer to the note itself (Say C4, F#6, Gb2, etc) and frequencies would refer to the actual sound waves created. Or at least thats how I've usually seen the terms used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as it turns out, the problem was completely unrelated to what I thought it might be.

Turns out there was a single equation I had written in my sampler that was just blatantly wrong.

After 2048 samples had been played, I would just kinda loop back to the beginning of the waveform, causing the popping.

I honestly have no idea why I wrote that in, but hey, it works now.